# Tcp server with accept list in C#

Tags: c#, tcp, client, server

I have a tcp server/client system , and I just want to accept specific clients, so I create an accept list and check client ip after accept it and then close the connection if it's not in the accept list. this solution leads to a performance problem because of the large number of clients.
How can I get client ip before accept the connection? Or are there any other ways to handle this problem?

my code:

```
TcpClient tcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
if (!acceptList.Contains(tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint))
{
    tcpClient.Close();
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot access remote endpoint information before accepting the client in C#.

In unmanaged code, an application can decide whether to accept the connection by supplying a callback method in the [`WSAAccept()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741513(v=vs.85).aspx) call. Perhaps with enough P/Invoke skills you could make that call yourself; I doubt it's worth the effort though.

Also curious what scenario you're in, that these "rogue clients" are causing performance problems. Do you really get thousands of undesired connection attempts? You might consider using a firewall instead.

Comment: thanks for your answer, your keyword helps me to find some other threads related to this problem , It seems you are right, there's no equivalent for WSAAccept() in .NET.